# pydantic: how to make a choice of types for a field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I have a FastAPI app and I need to create a Car class in which the attributes *wheel* and *speed* can take an int **or** str type. How to do it? This code does not work, because *wheel* and *speed* will have only an integer type (not str in second print):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Car(BaseModel):
    wheel: int | str
    speed: int | str


bmw = Car(wheel=4, speed=250)
mercedes = Car(wheel='4', speed='200')

print(type(bmw.wheel), type(bmw.speed))
print(type(mercedes.wheel), type(mercedes.speed))
```

Result is:

```
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I would personally just use `pydantic.StrictInt` and `pydantic.StricStr` here (and actually, I use those almost everywhere, particularly `StrictStr` because practically any object can be coerced to a string):

```
import pydantic


class Car(pydantic.BaseModel):
    wheel: pydantic.StrictInt | pydantic.StrictStr
    speed: pydantic.StrictInt | pydantic.StrictStr


bmw = Car(wheel=4, speed=250)
mercedes = Car(wheel='4', speed='200')

print(type(bmw.wheel), type(bmw.speed))
print(type(mercedes.wheel), type(mercedes.speed))
```

This prints:

```
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

There is order in the type specification. With `int | str`, the value will be treated as an `int` if possible, otherwise a `str`. Reversing the order `str | int` will result in the values being treated as `str` if possible, otherwise `int`. The problem with reversing the order is that pretty much everything can be treated as a `str` so the `bmw` values will be cast to `str`. Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Car(BaseModel):
    wheel: str | int
    speed: str | int


bmw = Car(wheel=4, speed=250)
mercedes = Car(wheel='4', speed='200')

print(type(bmw.wheel), type(bmw.speed))
print(type(mercedes.wheel), type(mercedes.speed))
```

```
<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
```

The key here is that you need to choose which type takes precedence.

Comment: yes, it is, but you may use StrictInt or StrictStr in pydantic and it solves problem, when you want that string "1" will be a string, or number 1 will be an integer

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is the Union option from typing. An example is below

```
from typing import Union
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Car(BaseModel):
    wheel: Union[str,int]
    speed: Union[str,int]
```

Further, instead of simple str or int you can write your own classes for those types in pydantic and add more attributes as needed.

Comment: `int | str` and `Union[int, str]` are completely equivalent.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes they trully are, thanks for pointing out. However , for older versions of python one needs to use the Union operator because pydantic does not support the ``|`` operator. So, my answer offers a solution applicable both to new and old python versions.